# R subprocess failed when launched from windows task manager

Tags: windows, subprocess, scheduler

***Setup & Config***

Windows 10
[1] "R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)

A C:/test.r containing

```
library(subprocess)
is_windows <- function () (tolower(.Platform$OS.type) == "windows")
R_binary <- function () {
  R_exe <- ifelse (is_windows(), "R.exe", "R")
  return(file.path(R.home("bin"), R_exe))
}
handle <- spawn_process(R_binary(), c("--no-save")) 
Sys.sleep(1)
print(handle)
process_write(handle, 'n <- 10\n')
process_write(handle, "rnorm(10)\n")
process_read(handle, PIPE_STDOUT, timeout = 1000)
```

***Results***

1 - Launching test.R in a Rgui.exe/Rterm.exe everything works

2 - Launching test.R through task scheduler I got the following error

Error in spawn_process(R_binary(), c("--no-save")) : 
  could not create process: Accès refusé ("Access refused")
Exécution arrêtée ("Excution stopped")

You can launch test.R by doing a manual task scheduler task or by

```
install.packages("taskscheduleR")
library(taskscheduleR)
myscript <- system.file("extdata", "helloworld.R", package = "taskscheduleR")
myscript="C:/test..r"
taskscheduler_create(taskname = "myfancyscript", rscript = myscript,
    schedule = "ONCE", starttime = format(Sys.time() + 10*60, "%H:%M"))
taskcheduler_runnow("myfancyscript")
```

(Then you can read the error log in the subprocess directory)

***Question ?***

It seems that a R process launched by task scheduler has lower right and fail to launch a subprocess, why ? 
I already tried to put the task scheduler process with the highest privilege but it failed !

Thanks

Comment: IS there someone to take the challenge ?

Comment: It's now working when I launch these tasks from System scheduler instead of the windows task scheduler. I don't know what's wrong with the windows task scheduler but something wrong^^